# How to provide Information symbol in vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

I want provide symbol of Information in vbscript.

Here is my code:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
lol=msgbox ("Update successful",10,"Information")
```

I want to provide Information(Exclaim) symbol before the message "Update successful". 
[image]

Can anybody please suggest me how to provide it?

Comment: Add 64 (information icon) to the buttons parameter. From Help at https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=2764

Comment: PS `10` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vbInformation`
like that :

```
lol=msgbox ("Update successful",vbInformation,"Information")
```

For more information about **[MsgBox Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1ft6yf3%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)**